# How to add n:m relation to FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following Rails models:

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  validates :project_assignments, length: { minimum: 1, message: "must have at least one PM" }

  has_many :project_assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :project_managers, through: :project_assignments, source: :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_assignments, allow_destroy: true, update_only: true
end

class ProjectAssignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :project_assignments
end
```

Since `project_managers` are required to create a project, I'm trying to add them directly as `nested_attribute` to my factory:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project do
    title { Faker::Book.unique.title }
    sequence(:number) { |n| n }
    customer
    project_assignments do
      user = create(:user)
      { user_id: user.id }
    end
  end
end
```

But then I get this error: `ProjectAssignment(#32880) expected, got [:user_id, 9] which is an instance of Array(#9400)`.

I've also tried to create a `ProjectAssignment` factory like this ...

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project_assignment do
    project
    user
  end
end
```

... and create the project like this ...

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project do
    title { Faker::Book.unique.title }
    sequence(:number) { |n| n }
    customer

    before(:create) do |project|
      create_list(:project_assignment, 2)
      project.reload
    end
  end
end
```

... but then FactoryBot runs an infinite loop until is doesn't have any unique `Project` titles anymore.

## Solution

Oh no, silly me. It has to be ...

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project do
    title { Faker::Book.unique.title }
    sequence(:number) { |n| n }
    customer
    project_assignments_attributes do
      user = create(:user)
      [{ user_id: user.id }]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can't create a project if doesn't have at least 1 project assignment, and you can't create a project assignment if it doesn't have a project, there's something strange with that dependency or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm creating the project with `nested_attributes`, so this is not a problem: `Project.create(title: "Foobar", project_assigments_attributes: [ { user_id: 1}])`

Comment: try setting the project to the project_assignment:
`
  before(:create) do |project|
      create_list(:project_assignment, 2, project: project)
    end
`